# Linq select the items that have unique foreign key and ignore the items that has duplicated foreign key

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

Let's say I have two tables, `Comment` `{ Id , PostId }` and `Post` `{ Id }`.

Now I want to retrieve the comments that have different `PostId` property, should not have two or more comments with same `PostId` in my query result.

Is that possible with Linq?

My code:

```
var MyPosts = _context.PostComments
                      .Include(a => a.ApplicationUser)
                      .Include(a => a.Post)
                      .OrderByDescending(a => a.DateTime)
                      .Select(a => a.Post)
                      .Take(25);
    
PostComments = _context.PostComments
                       .Include(a => a.ApplicationUser)
                       .Include(a => a.Post)
                       .OrderByDescending(a => a.DateTime)
                       .Where(a => a.Id != null 
                                   && MyPosts.Where(p => p.Id == a.PostId).Count() < 2)
                       .Take(25);
```

Comment: Why Take(25)? From question it is not clear why you have used OrderByDescending?

Comment: it is not neccessary to use orderby , the question is about how to use distinct but with ForgienKey

Comment: From you requirement, I think you need change the relationship, be sure it is one-to-one relationship. Then it will not have duplicated foreign key in your table.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```cs
var postComments = _context.PostComments;

var MyPosts = 
    from d in postComments.Select(d => new { d.PostId }).Distinct()
    from pc in postComments
        .Include(pc => pc.ApplicationUser)
        .Include(pc => pc.Post)
        .Where(pc => pc.PostId == d.PostId)
        .OrderByDescending(pc => pc.DateTime)
        .Take(1);
    select pc;
```

Comment: I think "Where statement" should be like " .Where(pc => pc.Id == d.Id) " , is that right?

Comment: No, it should be as in answer